# Android 'List', "get" function giving me error.

Tags: android, arraylist

So this is my list in my custom adapter. I am stuck as the "getItem" function and getView function aren't running due to error 
"Incompatible Types:
 Required: in.paperbind.app.shopping 
 Actual: java.lang.Object

I cannot understand as to why I am incurring this error. Can someone please help me?

```
public class productAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List items = new ArrayList();

public productAdapter(Context context, List items)
{
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.items = items;
}

public products getItem(int position)
{
    return items.get(position);
}

public long getItemID(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    products p = items.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(p.getName());
    if (p.getImage() != null) {
        holder.pic.setImageBitmap(p.getImage());
    } else {
        // MY DEFAULT IMAGE
        holder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.grocerybag);
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    ImageView pic;
}
```

}

Comment: Check Java name conventions. You have to specify list type `List<shopping>`

Comment: **Required: in.paperbind.app.shopping
Actual: java.lang.Object**. That should give you a hint. What is `items` list  of products?

Answer (score 1):

define your list as:

```
private List<products> items = new ArrayList<products>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a generic list, meaning that you didn't define which type of objects is stored inside the list, so Java assumes all of your items are `Object`s (the lowest common denominator of all objects).

Change your list instantiation to this line:

```
private List<Shopping> items = new ArrayList<Shopping>();
```

and change the rest of your code accordingly. This will help resolve your issues.
Do not use explicit casting as suggested here - this overrides Java's type checking and ensures problems down the road.

Answer (score -2):

Your list contains `Object` instances and your `getItem(int position)` method is expected to return `products` instance.
Add cast to `products` instance like this:

```
public products getItem(int position)
{
    return (products) items.get(position);
}
```

`Object` class is the superclass object in Java that handles basic memory allocation operations and all classes, implicitly or explicitly, extend that class.